# How can I add a checkbox before text & when the checkbox is checked by the user the text gets deleted but remains in the list?

Tags: javascript

I tried several times to add the checkbox before the text but its not working. Can anyone tell me what should I do?

```
function showTasks() {
  let getLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem("New Todo"); //get local storage
  if (getLocalStorage == null) {
    //if local storage is null
    listArr = []; //create empty array
  } else {
    listArr = JSON.parse(getLocalStorage); //convert json string into a js object
  }
  const pendingNumb = document.querySelector(".pendingNumb");
  pendingNumb.textContent = listArr.length; //pass the length in pendingNumb
  if (listArr.length > 0) {
    deleteAllBtn.classList.add("active");
  } else {
    deleteAllBtn.classList.remove("active");
  }

  let newLiTag = "";
  let x = document.createElement("input");
  x.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");

  listArr.forEach((element, index) => {
    newLiTag += `<li>${element}<span onclick = "deleteTask(${index})" ><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></span> </li>`;
  });

  todoList.innerHTML = newLiTag; //add new li tag inside ul
  inputBox.value = ""; //make input field blank once task added
}
```

Comment: Please present a proper [mre] when asking questions like this.

Comment: Where did you put the `x`? is it supposed to be appended into HTML doc tree?

Comment: @CBroe From next time I'll present a minimal reproducible code. Problem solved. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to add a checkbox before each ToDo item. If that is the case, your code is not doing that. You created only one `<input type="checkbox">` element and assigned it to the `x` variable, but you are not using it anywhere.

I simplified your code to focus on the creation of the `<li>` elements with a checkbox for each one of them. The snippet is bellow. You can click on the `Run code snippet` button to see it is action.

```js
// Simulating a list of ToDos
const listArr = ['buy bread', 'save for a PS5'];

function showTasks() {
  // array to store the ToDo elements
  const listItems = [];

  // for each item, create an <li> element containing an <input type="checkbox">,
  // the ToDo value and a <button> for delete action
  listArr.forEach((element, index) => {
    let li = `<li id="todo_${index}">`;
    li += `<input type="checkbox" value="${index}" />`;
    li += element;
    li += ` <button onclick="deleteTask(${index})">Delete</button>`;
    li += '</li>';
    listItems.push(li);
  });

  // join array items, resulting in a string containing all of the <li> elements 
  document.querySelector('#todo_list').innerHTML = listItems.join('');
}

function deleteTask (index) {
  console.log(`Delete element ${index}`);
}

showTasks();
```

```html
<ul id="todo_list">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your span has

> onclick = "deleteTask(${index})

But it's not provided here. What do you have for that function?

Comment: All the functions were working fine only checkbox was not working.